# Citrix XenDesktop 7.1 hide local drives

Tags: group-policy, xenapp, xendesktop

I have currently testing Citrix Xen Desktop 7.1. I am delivering applications from Server 2008 R2. When users login to a app via the Storefront they are able to access the local drives on the server. I would like to not allow access to the local drives. I can not find a Citrix Policy to do this. Maybe I am just looking over it. I believe I can do this with a GPO if I have to.

I would also like to run a login script to add their network drives. I have not looked into the login script yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this VIA gpo. The setting you want is "Hide these specified drives in My Computer" It is located in: User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer

For network drives you can use a GPO as well.
User Configuration -> Preferences -> windows settings -> Drive maps

Comment: I actually do not think I can use a GPO. Because, I only want this applied to people using XenDesktop to run applications. I do not want users who login locally to the PC to be blocked from seeing the local drives. I just can't believe there is not a way of doing this in Citrix.

Comment: @Jmcgee73 Use loopback: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287

Answer (score 0):

I did end up using loopback GPO to apply the policy to just users on this machine. I then used the Drive Maps GPO in "User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps" to hide the drives. This GPO allows filtering for users not in a certain security group. I filtered by not Domain Admins. I found the instructions here.

Thanks!

http://www.travisrunyard.com/2013/03/26/xenapp-6-5-hide-local-drives/